# I have a div that I can't interact with

Tags: css, html, non-interactive

The website is here:

http://www.ourcourse.ca/Pages/Drama/dramaresources.php

And I just realized I can't highlight text or click on links in the centre div. I read somewhere that having an overlapping div might cause the issue... so I tried changing the z-index to be greater than the top navigation bar that overlaps, but that didn't help.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you add the value of ids in double quotes here  <div id= Centre> 
                  <div id= Content_div><h1>Drama Resources </h1><p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving a negative `z-index` to the `<div>` with `id="Centre"`, which is causing your problem.

In ***mainstyle.css***:

```
#Main #Centre {
  ...
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Remove that and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks.. this explains why I couldn't interact with it. Now it seems to work. Although changing the z-index makes the top nav bar hide beneath the centre divs. Is it possible to have the nav bar on top, but still interact with the content_div?

Comment: @SamanthaOdber It works for me in Chome. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: She might be in IE, you can add a positive z-index to the nav bar to ensure it is placed above the centre div.

Comment: no, I was working in Chrome. But I came across the same answer as you Colin, positive z-index worked fine. Could not have a negative z-index on my centre div, or it wouldn't interact. And, also, I didn't know the divs had to be positions for z-index to affect them. Thank you for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the z-index. It's causing the div containing the clickable link to sit behind it's wrapper.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the suggestions a try and see.